# Call a Google App Script externally

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Jenkins job which does certain work and send the output to my Gmail inbox. I have developed a google app script which will read my mails and update some data in my google sheets when I trigger it manually.

I tried to deploy it on web app server so that I'll be able to call it externally but I'm stuck with some queries.

As an example, lets' say I have the below app script and want this to be triggered externally.

```
function addProduct() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("5780945843058");
  sheet.appendRow(['Cotton Sweatshirt XL', '$12']);
}
```

1. What should I be writing in the `doGet()`? I'm not exactly sure how to frame up my code to make this work. I looked at some examples but I'm confused.
2. How can I make this run externally without the end user having to sign-in as I would be triggering this from Jenkins/Python?

Kindly clarify.

Comment: Publish your webapp to execute as you (no one signs in), add a code guard (i.e. check for a secret signature in the request) (no one can act like you but you), and then call your function from the relevant GET / POST event handler

Comment: I have generated the Current web app URL and when I run it by hitting in the URL, i get `Script function not found: doGet` but when i test with `Test web app for your latest code.`, i am able to get the required output. what am i missing here

Comment: `/exec` runs only a saved snapshot of your script as from *File -> Manage Versions*, while `/dev` will run the script from its current state (last time you clicked the little "save" button or ran any function in the Script Editor). Was there a `doGet` function when you last saved a version?

Comment: i was able to figure out the error. I have to save as new version always. I'm able to get the output when I launch the URL in the browser and also in the incognito mode. But when i try to trigger the same URL from python, i see a HTTP 200 but the desired output is now happening, how can i call this URL externally ?

Comment: @sdgd Its a more involved process but you could also leverage the [App Script REST API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts/) whose [scripts resource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts) allows you to remotely invoke an apps script function. There's also a [Python client library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python) available.